# MongoDB bucket boundaries

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

How to use MongoDB aggregation to use $bucket to get the output for the below records

| Name | value |
| --- | --- |
| N1 | 0 |
| N2 | 20 |
| N3 | 0.01 |
| N4 | 50 |
| N5 | 10 |
| N6 | 20 |
| N7 | 0 |
| N8 | 11 |
| N9 | 35 |
| N10 | 51 |

Boundaries for this should be on 'value' column:

1. ' =0
2. ' >0 and <=10
3. ' >10 and <=20
4. ' >20 and <= 30
5. ' >30

Note - value 0.01 should be in the range '>0 and <=10'

Answer (score 0):

Pls refer to https://mongoplayground.net/p/V9mjIw1HmYK

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $bucket: {
      groupBy: "$N",
      // Field to group by
      boundaries: [
        0,
        1,
        10.1,
        20.1,
        30.1,
        1000
      ],
      // Boundaries for the buckets
      default: "Other",
      // Bucket id for documents which do not fall into a bucket
      output: {
        // Output for each bucket
        "count": {
          $sum: 1
        },
        "data": {
          $push: {
            "N": "$N"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  
])
```